# How to remove facebook like text in gigya social share button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, facebook, c#-4.0, gigya

I have implemented Gigya Social Sharing in our website and my requirement is like the share buttons should be displayed without counter.I achieved it but for "facebook-like" button a text("2 Peoples like this") is getting displayed. How to avoid/hide that text.

[image: FB Like text]

Comment: Why don't you ask Gigya?  What they say?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is just not possible with jQuery, because of how the button is created.

The "Facebook-Like" button is loaded in an IFRAME that is entirely under the control of Facebook. In this case Gigya only facilitates the creation of the IFRAME. Because the contents are inside of an IFRAME whose contents are dynamically by Facebook, it is not possible to manipulate in this way.

You should instead pass the parameter "showCounts":"none" into the call to socialize.showShareBarUI which creates the like button. This will hide any counts.

Additionally, you should be aware that making any changes to Facebook's internal web controls in this way is considered to be a violation of Facebook's Style/Branding Policies.

Comment: after passing the parameter "showCounts":"none" iam getting this